# Copy the result of a order by query into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help to copy the order by queries result into another table.I have tried many possiblities.But nothing seems to work. I have tried the following ways.The problem is the results are getting copied to the new table without ordering by. Don know y it is?

```
select * into table2  from table1 order by col_name
```

Comment: Tables in MySQL don't have a specific order. How can you tell if they're being copied in the desired order?

Comment: I'm confused.  In MySQL, `into` is used for files or variables, not for tables.  Are you really using SQL Server?  If so, tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY col_name
```

Comment: This is how to do it - but as @Barmar said in his initial comment, there is no reason to do it. Even when you run a SELECT against the new table, you will still have to supply some ORDER By info, otherwise you may not get the expected results.

Comment: This doesn't insert sorted result.. Simply inserting the table 1 values as it is..